# Minimal Extendable Open source Software for web access to video camera feed on a windows 10 tablet

Tags: windows, open-source, web-apps, camera

I have an unattended windows 10 x86 tablet that I use as a server on battery for about 10 hours a day (with windows CS (connected standby) disabled).

I would really like to start the software on my tablet, go to another computer. access the server's IP:port in a browser   and see the video stream.

It would be nice if  there is no connection to the web stream , the camera will be put on standby (to not consume power).

I am also a programmer on various techs and it would also be rally nice if I could plug in/extend it's behavior with image processing and an alert systems.

Answer (score 1):

The Open Computer Vision, [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), is where you need to start.

- It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android.
- The library includes numerous examples.
- There is an example [here](https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/mjpg_serve.py) of using the python bindings to start a server for that could be extended to switch the camera off on disconnect and on on connect.
- It is probably the best possible starting point for your Image Processing.

Comment: Thank you the python sample link is really small. I also found some interesting command line app : `commandCam` that can mabye be piped through `nc`

Comment: Seams I don't have a camera on my laptop to develop this. Do you know how an easy way I can create fake camera stream/device to use in opencv?

Comment: Easiest way is to plug in a Web cam but you can stream from a file or a Web location as well.

Comment: Steve Barnes : extended the code (first time doing python) to do multithreading and sleep camera after it is not used for an amount of time https://github.com/ovidiubuligan/PythonHttpWebCam . Used PyInstaller to create a python independent release that runs on my tablet.

Comment: Also I had to use the front camera source since  the back camera doesn't work ,without any error message.  (Windows 10 cammera app works with back camera )

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan - it sounds like you are off to a great start - I have had some problems in the past with windows grabbing hold of, and keeping, resources that I didn't know that it was grabbing - this allowed windows programs that were "in the club" to get those resources and nobody else. It is worth checking if you have any background programs running that might use the camera.